# How to automatically rebase branch on push via GitHub Actions

Tags: git, github, github-actions, rebase

I'm trying to integrate Figma-tokens plugin with my repo. It can push new tokens to a specific repo branch and in specific location.

My main branch is protected and I want to review any changes from design team. That's why I've built a pipeline like this:

```
name: Generate PR from "design" branch

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - design

jobs:
  generatePR:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      - name: Checkout
        uses: actions/checkout@v3
        with:
          fetch-depth: 0
          ref: main

      - name: Reset promotion branch
        run: |
          git fetch origin design:design
          git reset --hard design

      - name: Create pull request
        uses: peter-evans/create-pull-request@v4
        id: cpr
        with:
          token: ${{ secrets.FIGMA_PAT }}
          branch: main-promotion
          labels: auto-generated, review-required
          title: Update design tokens

      - name: Check PR output
        if: ${{ steps.cpr.outputs.pull-request-number }}
        run: |
          echo "Pull Request Number - ${{ steps.cpr.outputs.pull-request-number }}"
          echo "Pull Request URL - ${{ steps.cpr.outputs.pull-request-url }}"
```

On push to `design` branch it open a PR (if not exists) to `main`  branch via `main-promotion` branch.

The problem is when integration push new commit to `design` branch and PR is opened it contains all commits from previous integration PRs like so:

1. Push `commitA` to `design` trigger workflow to open PR with `commitA` in it.
2. I've merged it to main branch successfully.
3. Push `commitB` to `design` trigger workflow to open PR again. But this time there're `commitA` and `commitB` in it. But I've already merged `commitA`, so it should not be there.

Is there any way to rebase branch (design or promotion one) before opening a PR?

Comment: Rebasing requires using Git, which can stop with merge conflicts; there are some bots that know how to do some of this but they're kind of limited. You may need to write your own.